# Cannot call value of non-function type "UIViewController?"

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to make an alert dialog showing up with messages and here's my code in ViewController.swift:

```
func showErrorAlert(title: String , msg: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    presentedViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The last line is giving me an error:

> "Cannot call value of non-function type "UIViewController?""

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT:
For Swift 3, change it to

```
present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

You called the wrong function.

Should be

```
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of `presentedViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Change to self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil) solving this problem too.

Comment: `presentViewController` gave me the same error, only `self.present` worked